# Efficient way to invert the hierarchy of a dict of dicts?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries that I want to invert. - analogous to flipping the axes on a chart. So I'm starting with:

```
dict_by_years = {
    2012: {}, 
    2013: {
        'US': 84,
        'CN': 394, 
        'JP': 171, 
        'TW': 39,
    }, 
    2014: {
        'US': 70, 
        'CN': 444, 
        'JP': 155, 
        'TW': 43,
    },   
    2015: { 
        'US': 76,
        'CN': 430, 
        'JP': 141,
        'TW': 39,
        'PH': 15,
    },
}
```

And I want to end up with:

```
dict_by_country_codes = {
    'US': {
        2013: 84,
        2014: 70,
        2015: 76,
    },
    'CN': {
        2013: 394,
        2014: 444,
        2015: 430,
    },
    'JP': {
        2013: 171,
        2014: 155,
        2015: 141,
    },
    'TW': {
        2013: 39,
        2014: 43,
        2015: 39,
    },
    'PH': {
        2015: 15,
    }
}
```

Of course, the data will be inconsistent and unpredictable. Is there a better way to achieve this than to just iterate through each level of hierarchy and add the values up in the new dict structure?

Comment: Iterating is one reasonable way to do it.  What have you tried, and why is iterating not a sufficient solution?

Comment: What inconsistencies and/or unpredictable things do you need to account for?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(dict)
for a, b in dict_by_years.items():
   for c, _d in b.items():
      d[c][a] = _d
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps(dict(d), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
"US": {
    "2013": 84,
    "2014": 70,
    "2015": 76
},
"CN": {
    "2013": 394,
    "2014": 444,
    "2015": 430
},
"JP": {
    "2013": 171,
    "2014": 155,
    "2015": 141
},
"TW": {
    "2013": 39,
    "2014": 43,
    "2015": 39
},
"PH": {
    "2015": 15
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use next code:

```
dict_by_country_codes = {}
for year, countries in dict_by_years.items():
    for country, value in countries.items():
        if country in dict_by_country_codes:
            dict_by_country_codes[country][year] = value
        else:
            dict_by_country_codes[country] = {year: value}
```